# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, sass

Node version: v12.13.0
Ionic version: 5.4.16
Node-sass: 4.13.1
libsass: 3.5.4
MacOS: 10.15.3

npm rebuild node-sass --force did not help

Comment: tried to downgrade node-sass to 4.12 also did not work

Answer (score 2):

1. npm --depth 9999 update
2. npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: The --depth option is no longer supported in newer node versions.
see  https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md